# Android MediaPlayer Clipping on Restart after seekTo

Tags: java, android, media-player

I am using an Android MediaPlayer to play from a local source.  It is working well other than one bug when restarting the sound.

```
public void create() {
   FileInputStream in = mApp.openFileInput(mMusicFile);
   mp = new MediaPlayer();
   mp.setDataSource(in.getFD());
   mp.prepare();
   mp.setLooping(true);
}

public void play() {
   mp.start();
}

public void stop() {
   mp.stop();
   mp.prepare();
   mp.seekTo(0);
}
```

If I call stop(), then a second or so later call play() I hear a brief clip of the sound where it had been stopped then it sound restarts.

Comment: Why are you calling mp.prepare() in your stop() method?

Comment: So after I call stop() it will be in the same state as before I called play()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a known bug in Android 2.2 Froyo.  The prescribed work around is to delete the MediaPlayer and make a new one or fade in to the playback.

The internal buffers are not being flushed after the seek.